# Need explanation on the concept of data rate in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I have built a model in simulink.

The model uses Bernoulli Binary Generator as its input.

Now I have set the BBG block as below
[image]

What I want to do: I would like to vary the data rate.

In simulink, the sample time means the steps at which the block generates its output.

Ex: if I set "Sample Time" = 0.01 and the duration of simulation is 1000, does that mean I am transferring 100 bits/second?

Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for all blocks, the Sample Time indicates the time interval at which a block gets executed.
So with the set up you have, the block outputs a new random binary number every 0.01s, and hence you are correct that you are generating 100 numbers per second, so 100 bits/second.

Some blocks, such as this one, also allow you to output a frame based signal.
You are not doing this, but it is worth mentioning how that effects block execution.
Lets say that you selected Frame based outputs and set a frame size of 100.
Then the block would be executed every 0.01*100 = 1s.
That is, you would get a new frame of 100 new bits every second.
So you still have an overall bit rate of 100 bits/second.